# Can anyone tell me how can I use cloudinary with react-hook-form and zod in nextjs

Tags: next.js, react-hook-form, cloudinary

I'm aiming to use React Hook Form and Zod to efficiently store multiple images on Cloudinary. Despite my search, I haven't come across any online resources or tutorials that address this specific topic. If anyone could provide guidance or assistance, it would be immensely appreciated.

I tried this method but when I submit question the images remain empty.

```
'use client'
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { SubmitHandler, useForm } from 'react-hook-form'
import { zodResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/zod'
import { QuestionForm } from '@/utils/QuestionSchemaZod'
import type { QuestionFormT } from '@/utils/QuestionSchemaZod'
import ImageUpload from '@/components/ImageUpload'
import {z} from "zod"
import axios from 'axios'

type Props = {}

const Question2 = (props: Props) => {
    const {
        register,
        handleSubmit,
        trigger,
        reset,
        formState: { errors, isValid }
    } = useForm<QuestionFormT>({
        resolver: zodResolver(QuestionForm)
    })
    const [formArray, setFormArray] = useState<any[]>([]); // Array to store form data
    const [imageUrls, setImageUrls] =useState<string[]>([])
    const [info, updateinfo] = useState<any>()
    const handleImageChange = () => {
        const stringimages = JSON.stringify(imageUrls)
        console.log(stringimages)
        register('images', { value: stringimages }); 
    }
    
    const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<QuestionFormT> = (data) => {
        console.log(data.subject);
        console.log(data);
        reset()
        setFormArray((prevFormArray) => [...prevFormArray, data]);
    };
    console.log(formArray);

    console.log(isValid)

  return (
    <>
        <button
            onClick={() => trigger()}
            className="bg-blue-400 rounded p-2 mb-2 mt-10 text-white"
        >
            Display Data Requirements
        </button>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className='flex flex-col'>
            <label htmlFor="subject"
                className="text-xl text-white"
            >Name:</label>
            <select id="subject" {...register("subject")}
                className='w-full block h-[50px] border-[1px] rounded-lg focus:border-blue-500 px-3 focus:border-2 outline-none'
                placeholder="Maths"
                
            >
                <option value='Maths'>Maths</option>
                <option value='GK'>GK</option>
                <option value='English'>English</option>
            </select>
            {errors.subject &&
                <p className="bg-yellow-100 text-red-500 italic px-2 py-1 rounded-md self-start">
                    {errors.subject?.message}
            </p>}

            <label htmlFor="question"
                className="text-xl text-white"
            >Question:</label>
            <input id="question" type="text" {...register("question")}
                className='w-full block h-[50px] border-[1px] rounded-lg focus:border-blue-500 px-3 focus:border-2 outline-none'
                placeholder="What is the capital of India"
            />
            {errors.question &&
                <p className="bg-yellow-100 text-red-500 italic px-2 py-1 rounded-md self-start">
                    {errors.question?.message}
            </p>}
            <div className='grid md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-4 sm:grid-cols-2 grid-cols-1 gap-5 sm:gap-10'>

            <div>
            <label htmlFor="options"
                className="text-xl text-white"
            >Options:</label>
            <input id="options" type="text" {...register("option1")}
                className='w-full block h-[50px] border-[1px] rounded-lg focus:border-blue-500 px-3 focus:border-2 outline-none'
                placeholder="option"
            />
            </div>
            <div>

            <label htmlFor="options"
                className="text-xl text-white"
            >Options:</label>
            <input id="options" type="text" {...register("option2")}
                className='w-full block h-[50px] border-[1px] rounded-lg focus:border-blue-500 px-3 focus:border-2 outline-none'
                placeholder="option"
            />
            </div>
            <div>

            <label htmlFor="options"
                className="text-xl text-white"
            >Options:</label>
            <input id="options" type="text" {...register("option3")}
                className='w-full block h-[50px] border-[1px] rounded-lg focus:border-blue-500 px-3 focus:border-2 outline-none'
                placeholder="option"
            />
            </div>
            <div>

            <label htmlFor="options"
                className="text-xl text-white"
            >Options:</label>
            <input id="options" type="text" {...register("option4")}
                className='w-full block h-[50px] border-[1px] rounded-lg focus:border-blue-500 px-3 focus:border-2 outline-none'
                placeholder="option"
            />
            </div>

            </div>

            <label htmlFor="answer"
                className="text-xl text-white"
            >Options:</label>
            <input id="answer" type="text" {...register("answer")}
                className='w-full block h-[50px] border-[1px] rounded-lg focus:border-blue-500 px-3 focus:border-2 outline-none'
                placeholder="answer"
            />

            <label htmlFor="explaination"
                className="text-xl text-white"
            >Options:</label>
            <input id="explaination" type="text" {...register("explanation")}
                className='w-full block h-[50px] border-[1px] rounded-lg focus:border-blue-500 px-3 focus:border-2 outline-none'
                placeholder="explanation"
            />
            <ImageUpload info={info} updateInfo={updateinfo} imageUrls={imageUrls} setImageUrls={setImageUrls} handleImageChange={handleImageChange}/>
            <div className='flex items-center justify-center mt-5'>
                <button type="submit" className={`px-6 py-3 text-white cursor-pointer mt-8 inline-block mb-2 bg-blue-500 rounded-xl shadow-lg`}>
                        Add Question
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div>
        </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Question2
```

```
import { z } from "zod"

export const QuestionForm = z.object({
    subject: z.string().refine(value => !!value, {
        message: "Subject is mandatory"
    }),
    question: z.string().refine(value => !!value, {
        message: "Question is mandatory"
    }),
    option1: z.string().refine(value => !!value, {
        message: "Option 1 is mandatory"
    }),
    option2: z.string().refine(value => !!value, {
        message: "Option 2 is mandatory"
    }),
    option3: z.string().refine(value => !!value, {
        message: "Option 3 is mandatory"
    }),
    option4: z.string().refine(value => !!value, {
        message: "Option 4 is mandatory"
    }),
    answer: z.string().refine(value => !!value, {
        message: "Answer is mandatory"
    }),
    explanation: z.string().refine(value => !!value, {
        message: "Explanation is mandatory"
    }),
    images:z.string()
})

export type QuestionFormT = z.infer<typeof QuestionForm>
```

````
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import {CldUploadWidget} from "next-cloudinary"

type Props = {
    info:any
    updateInfo: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<any>>
    imageUrls: string[]
    setImageUrls:React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string[]>>
    handleImageChange: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void
}

const ImageUpload:React.FC<Props>  = ({info,updateInfo,imageUrls,setImageUrls,handleImageChange}) => {
    const onupload = (result:any) => {
        updateInfo(result.info.secure_url)
        const newImageUrl = result.info.secure_url
        setImageUrls(preImageUrls => [...preImageUrls, newImageUrl])
        handleImageChange(result)
    }

    const handleDeleteImage = (index:number)=>{
        setImageUrls(prevImageUrls => {
            const updateImageUrls = [...prevImageUrls]
            updateImageUrls.splice(index,1)
            return updateImageUrls
        })
    }
  return (
    <div>
        <div className='mb-10'>
            <CldUploadWidget uploadPreset='#####' onUpload={onupload}>
                {({open}:any) => {
                    function handleOnclick(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>){
                        e.preventDefault()
                        open()
                    }
                    return(
                        <button className='border-[1px] rounded-lg p-1 px-2' onClick={handleOnclick}>
                            Upload Product Images
                        </button>
                    )
                }}
            </CldUploadWidget>
        </div>
        <div className='grid lg:grid-cols-4 md:grid-cols-3 sm:grid-cols-2 grid-cols-1 gap-10'>
            {imageUrls.map((imageUrl, index) =>(
                <div key={index} className='flex flex-col justify-center'>
                    <img src={imageUrl} className='w-[250px] h-[300px] object-cover object-top' alt={`uploades Image ${index + 1}`} />
                    <button className='border-[1px] rounded-lg p-1 px-2 mt-5' onClick={() => handleDeleteImage(index)}>delete</button>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ImageUpload```
````

Comment: what do you mean by images remain empty? Do you get any error? This sounds like the issue is in the data flow. I haven't seen this particular use case but maybe these examples will help you here: https://github.com/colbyfayock/cloudinary-examples#nextjs